# Modificar una lista de manera dinámica para cada grupo de elementos en un juego iterativo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dispongo de un código que simula un juego de señales entre jugadores (ver código abajo). El juego consta de 4 jugadores y 4 señales, que juegan en parejas durante 3 rondas (ver `def main()`).

Definidas también en `main()`, existen en el juego unas variables `s1` y `s2` (llamémoslas sigmas) que afectan la dinámica del juego. De tal manera que en `def with_b` la variable `s1` afecta la ecuación que utilizan los jugadores 1 y 2, y la variable `s2` afecta la ecuación que utilizan los jugadores 3 y 4.

Estas variables `s1` y `s2` permanecen constantes a lo largo del juego tal y como está ahora: `s1=[1,0,0,0]` y `s2=[0,0,0,1]`

En el juego, para cada `ronda`, cada `jugador` genera una lista `aux` que representa la señal producida. Así, cada ronda, cada jugador producirá su `aux`, que podrá ser una de las siguientes: `[1,0,0,0]` o `[0,1,0,0]` o `[0,0,1,0]` o `[0,0,0,1]`.

**Objetivo**

Creamos dos listas nuevas: `s_inicial_1` y `s_inicial_2`.

Lo que se pretende ahora es que, para cada ronda y jugador, si su `aux` coincide con la lista `s_inicial` (`s_inicial_1` en caso de jugadores 1 y 2, `s_inicial_2` en caso de jugadores 3 y 4), se modifique el valor de su sigma `s1` o `s2` dentro del juego para ese jugador concreto según unos facotres de corrección.

Por ejemplo. Si en una ronda determinada el jugador 1 genera `aux1=[1,0,0,0]`, dado que esta lista coincide con `s_inicial_1=[1,0,0,0]`, el valor de `s1` se multiplicará por `cf_pos`. De esta manera el nuevo valor actualizado `s1` operará para jugador 1 en la función def `with_b`. Si por el contrario, jugador 1 genera `aux1=[0,0,1,0]`, dado que esta lista no coincide con `s_inicial_1=[1,0,0,0]`, el valor de `s1` (para ese jugador) se multiplicará por `cf_neg`. Los valores de `s1` o `s2` de cada jugador se irán actualizando acumulativamente ronda a ronda.

```
s1 = [1,0,0,0]
s_inicial_1 = [1,0,0,0]
s2 = [0,0,0,1]
s_inicial_2 = [0,0,0,1]
cf_pos = 0.9
cf_neg = 0.1
```

Para jugador 1:

```
if aux1 == s_inicial_1:
    s1[:] = [x * cf_pos for x in s1]
else:
    s1[:] = [x * cf_neg for x in s1]
```

Para jugador 2:

```
if aux2 == s_inicial_1:
    s1[:] = [x * cf_pos for x in s1]
else:
    s1[:] = [x * cf_neg for x in s1]
```

Para jugador 3:

```
if aux3 == s_inicial_2:
    s2[:] = [x * cf_pos for x in s2]
else:
    s2[:] = [x * cf_neg for x in s2]
```

Para jugador 4:

```
if aux4 == s_inicial_2:
    s2[:] = [x * cf_pos for x in s2]
else:
    s2[:] = [x * cf_neg for x in s2]
```

Un problema que observo es que en el código actual `aux` la estoy generando al escribir el archivo csv no en el juego en sí. También, que al ser `s1` y `s2` variables constantes, no sé cómo podría cambiarlas dinámicamente (de ronda en ronda) para cada jugador sin que ello cambiara también su valor de sigma para el resto de jugadores. Digamos que cada uno debería evolucionar su sigma independientemente.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque
import csv
import math

    s_inicial_1 = [1,0,0,0]
    s_inicial_2 = [0,0,0,1]

    class Partida():
        def __init__(self, jugadores, menLen, emparejamientos, senales, s1, s2, b, x, m):
            self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
            self.senales = senales
            self.s1 = s1
            self.s2 = s2
            self.b = b
            self.x = x
            self.m = m
            self.jugadores=jugadores
            self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(menLen)
                           for emparejamiento in emparejamientos[0]
                           for nombre in emparejamientos}
            self.memoria = list()
            self.entropy = float()

        def generar_senales(self):

            def with_b(muestra, observa, s1, s2, r, nombre):
                if nombre <=2:
                    if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                        (0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s1) + ((self.m / 8))
                    else:
                        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                        (0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s1) + ((self.m / 8))
                else:
                    if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                        (0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s2) + ((self.m / 8))
                    else:
                        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                        (0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s2) + ((self.m / 8))
                return result

            def choice(opciones, probs):
                probAcumuladas = list()
                aux = 0
                for p in probs:
                    aux += p
                    probAcumuladas.append(aux)
                r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
                op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
                return opciones[op]

            yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))

            r = 1
            while True:
                eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
                for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                    probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s1[indx],self.s2[indx], r, nombre)
                             for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                    eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
                r += 1
                yield eleccs

        def jugar(self):
            gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
                senales = next(gen_sens)
                self.memoria.append(senales)

                for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                    self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                    self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                    self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                    self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


        class Jugador():
            def __init__(self, menLen):
                 self.mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
                 self.men_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)


    def main():
        jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
        emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                           [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
                           [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

        patron = 1
        menLen = 2

        ####SIGMAS####
        s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
        s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]

        muestras = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02}]

        muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

        simulaciones = 10

        estadisticas = {sim: {jugador: {muestra: {senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                                            for senal in senales}
                                  for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                        for jugador in jugadores}
                    for sim in range(simulaciones)}

        for sim in range(simulaciones):
            for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                juego = Partida(jugadores, menLen, emparejamientos, senales, s1,s2, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                                muestras[mu]['m'])
                juego.jugar()
                for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                    for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                        estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('datos.csv','w', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                                    quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                writer.writerow(['Sim','Muestra', 'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'Patron', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales + ['sumpop'])
     # Escribiendo las estadisticas para cada jugador, ronda y muestra
                for jugador in jugadores:
                    for sim in range(simulaciones):
                        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                            for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                                aux = [estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                                aux1 = [estadisticas[sim][1][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                                aux2 = [estadisticas[sim][2][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                                aux3 = [estadisticas[sim][3][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                                aux4 = [estadisticas[sim][4][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                                print(aux)
    # Lista que contiene los sumatorios de cada tipo de senales producidas a nivel de la poblacion global en cada muestra y ronda
                                summation_pop = []
                                for i in range(len(aux1)):
                                    summation_pop.append(
                                        aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                                writer.writerow([sim +1, mu + 1, jugador, ronda, patron, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                                             muestras[mu]['m']] + aux + [summation_pop])

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

**Edición de código (27/06/2019, 21:19 gtm +00)**

- Edición de código. Se simplifica la variable `muestras` para facilitar la lectura de datos. Los valores `{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02}` permiten más variación en el outcome de aux, pues la ecuación implementada en `def with_b` modela deriva.
- Para tests: si `'b': 1.0` y `s1 = [1,0,0,0]` existe alta probabilidad de que jugadores 1 y 2 produzcan `aux = [1,0,0,0]`. Si `'b': 0.0`, existe más probabilidad de que los jugadores produzcan un aux diferente.

**Actualización final**

- La respuesta está contestada satisfactoriamente y la recompensa asignada. En esta nota adicional me gustaría añadir que el código original que compartí aquí no incluía una funcionalidad adicional que tenía implementado en mi código antiguo: la posibilidad de limitar el tamaño de la memoria de los agentes a un número determinado de rondas mediante la variable `memLen`. La implementación precisa cargar una librería `from collections import deque`. He editado el código proporcionado en la pregunta. Al haber cambiado tantas cosas, me preguntaba cuál sería la mejor manera de implementar una funconalidad similar en el código actual de la respuesta, si en la clase Partida o en la clase Jugador.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Actualización

Borro mi "respuesta" anterior, que era básicamente un comentario extendido, y lo reemplazo por lo siguiente, que sigue sin ser una respuesta definitiva pero ya se va a aproximando.

Lo primero que he hecho ha sido "refactorizar" tu código, para separar en dos clases `Jugador` y `Partida` lo que antes estaba en una sola. Los cambios que he realizado han sido los siguientes:

- La clase `Jugador` está ahora fuera de la clase `Partida`, y es más compleja pues no sólo guarda lo que el jugador ha visto, sino también su "sigma" y los parámetros necesarios para realizar la asignación de probabilidades a sus opciones. Es decir, la función `with_b`, que antes era "genérica" y recibía muchas cosas como parámetro, ahora es parte del comportamiento del jugador, por lo que en lugar de recibir como parámetro estas cosas las toma de los atributos del jugador. Esto permitirá en el futuro (todavía no) que cada jugador vaya modificando su sigma.
- La función `choice()`, que es de propósito general y no depende de la partida o del jugador, la he sacado y la he dejado como función genérica, en lugar de dejarla como una función interna dentro de otra, que es menos eficiente (al causar la redefinición de esta función interna cada vez que se ejecuta la externa)
- La `Partida`, en su inicialización, crea a los jugadores y le pasa a cada uno sus parámetros (lo que incluye sus sigmas). Para ello requiere, en vez de los parámetros `s1` y `s2` de antes, un diccionario cuyas claves sean los nombres de los jugadores y los valores las sigmas correspondientes.
- La función `generar_senales()` de la `Partida` se ha simplificado bastante ahora, invocando al método `with_b` de cada jugador.
- El programa principal debe crear el diccionario de sigmas antes explicado y pasárselo a la `Partida` al arrancar.
- El resto del código prácticamente no ha sido necesario tocarlo.

De paso he pasado todo el código a través del formateador automático "black" para que sea consistente en cosas como los espacios alrededor de las asignaciones, partir líneas largas apropiadamente, etc.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, seed
from bisect import bisect
import csv

s_inicial_1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
s_inicial_2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]

seed(1)

def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]


class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  # Hacer copia para que cada jugador tenga la suya
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        if not (muestra == observa == 0):
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        else:
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * 0 * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result


class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
            for nombre in pareja
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [
                    self.jugadores[nombre].with_b(
                        inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], r, indx
                    )
                    for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
                ]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

    patron = 1

    ####SIGMAS####
    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}

    muestras = [{"b": 0.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {
        sim: {
            jugador: {
                muestra: {
                    senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                    for senal in senales
                }
                for muestra in range(len(muestras))
            }
            for jugador in jugadores
        }
        for sim in range(simulaciones)
    }

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"],
            )
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

    with open("datos.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(
            csvfile, delimiter=";", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Sim", "Muestra", "Jugador", "Ronda", "Patron", "b", "x", "m"]
            + senales
            + ["sumpop"]
        )
        # Escribiendo las estadisticas para cada jugador, ronda y muestra
        for jugador in jugadores:
            for sim in range(simulaciones):
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [
                            estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux1 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][1][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux2 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][2][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux3 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][3][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux4 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][4][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        print(aux)
                        # Lista que contiene los sumatorios de cada tipo de senales producidas a nivel de la poblacion global en cada muestra y ronda
                        summation_pop = []
                        for i in range(len(aux1)):
                            summation_pop.append(aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                        writer.writerow(
                            [
                                sim + 1,
                                mu + 1,
                                jugador,
                                ronda,
                                patron,
                                muestras[mu]["b"],
                                muestras[mu]["x"],
                                muestras[mu]["m"],
                            ]
                            + aux
                            + [summation_pop]
                        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Al final, he cambiado tantas cosas que no estaba seguro de si seguiría funcionando correctamente, de modo que he hecho lo siguiente:

- He añadido al inicio del código un `random.seed(1)` para forzar a que el resultado sea siempre el mismo.
- He hecho lo mismo con tu código
- He ejecutado ambos y comparado el `.csv` que generan.

Salen .csv idénticos, por lo que estoy razonablemente seguro de que mi código se comporta como lo hacía el tuyo.

A partir de aquí vendría la parte que modifica el sigma de cada jugador. Esa parte no la he entendido, por lo que no la he implementado, pero debería ser mucho más simple ahora, ya que cada jugador tiene su propio `self.sigma` independiente. Dime en qué necesitarías ayuda para implementar esto.

## Actualización (2019-06-29)

Tratando de implementar la modificación del `self.sigma` según la elección de cada jugador, he tenido que hacer nuevas refactorizaciones:

- La elección que hace un jugador forma parte ahora del propio jugador. He implementado la función `Jugador.choose(r)` que recibe como parámetro la ronda, y esta función es llamada desde el generador `Partida.generar_senales()` para cada jugador. Esto simplifica bastante la función `generar_senales()` y permite que cada jugador sea "consciente" de qué elección ha hecho, lo que le permite generar su `aux` y compararlo con los `s_inicial` para así actualizar su sigma.
- En lugar de tener varias variables `s_inicial_1`, `s_inicial_2` he visto preferible tener una sola `s_inicial` que sería un diccionario cuyas claves son los números de jugador y los valores las listas `[1,0,0,0]` con las que tiene que comparar su `aux`.

Gracias a esta separación, cada jugador puede ahora actualizar su sigma tras cada elección de jugada. Este es el nuevo código, en el que he marcado con comentarios las partes modificadas:

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, seed
from bisect import bisect
import csv

## NUEVO
s_inicial = {
    1: [1, 0, 0, 0],
    2: [1, 0, 0, 0],
    3: [0, 0, 0, 1],
    4: [0, 0, 0, 1],
}

## NUEVO
cf_pos = 0.9
cf_neg = 0.1


seed(1)

def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]


class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  # Hacer copia para que cada jugador tenga la suya
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        if not (muestra == observa == 0):
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        else:
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * 0 * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result

    ## ESTA FUNCION ES NUEVA COMPLETAMENTE,
    def choose(self, r):
        # Esta parte del código se extrajo de Partida.generar_senales()
        # y se ha adaptado
        probs = [
            self.with_b(
                self.mem_mostradas[op], self.men_observadas[op], r, indx
            )
            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
        ]
        elecc = choice(self.senales, probs)

        # Esta parte es la que modifica el sigma. Se puede quitar por
        # completo y el código debería ser equivalente funcionalmente
        # al que teníamos antes (y al originalmente suministrado por el usuario)
        aux = [ (elecc==signal)+0 for signal in self.senales ]
        if aux == s_inicial[self.nombre]:
            self.sigma = [x * cf_pos for x in self.sigma]
        else:
            self.sigma = [x * cf_neg for x in self.sigma]
        return elecc


class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            ## NUEVO
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):
        ## NUEVO. Función muy simplificada al extraerse al Jugador la mayor parte
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores, self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = {}
            for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
                eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1

# El resto no se ha tocado
def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

    patron = 1

    ####SIGMAS####
    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}

    muestras = [{"b": 0.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {
        sim: {
            jugador: {
                muestra: {
                    senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                    for senal in senales
                }
                for muestra in range(len(muestras))
            }
            for jugador in jugadores
        }
        for sim in range(simulaciones)
    }

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"],
            )
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

    with open("datos.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(
            csvfile, delimiter=";", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Sim", "Muestra", "Jugador", "Ronda", "Patron", "b", "x", "m"]
            + senales
            + ["sumpop"]
        )
        # Escribiendo las estadisticas para cada jugador, ronda y muestra
        for jugador in jugadores:
            for sim in range(simulaciones):
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [
                            estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux1 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][1][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux2 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][2][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux3 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][3][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux4 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][4][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        print(aux)
                        # Lista que contiene los sumatorios de cada tipo de senales producidas a nivel de la poblacion global en cada muestra y ronda
                        summation_pop = []
                        for i in range(len(aux1)):
                            summation_pop.append(aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                        writer.writerow(
                            [
                                sim + 1,
                                mu + 1,
                                jugador,
                                ronda,
                                patron,
                                muestras[mu]["b"],
                                muestras[mu]["x"],
                                muestras[mu]["m"],
                            ]
                            + aux
                            + [summation_pop]
                        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Lo he ejecutado y, a pesar de que los sigmas se van modificando (he podido verificarlo con un depurador), el csv final sigue saliendo el mismo. Entiendo que debido a que sólo se juegan tres rondas (y tras ellas los sigma se reinician pues los jugadores se crean de nuevo), el efecto acumulativo de ir aplicando esas sigmas no llega a afectar a las probabilidades y por eso sigue saliendo el mismo resultado que cuando los sigma no se modificaban.

Aunque es posible también que, ya que sigo sin entender la mecánica del juego y me limito a refactorizar sin entender el objetivo último, haya implementado mal la parte que modifica los sigma. Tú me dirás si está correcto así.

Comment: @abufalia gracias por haberte tomado el tiempo de intentar comprender el problema. Se agradece. Intento ir respondiendo a las dudas. 1. El juego inicial se diseñó pensando en que las sigmas fueran constantes a lo largo de la simulación. Ahora, en efecto, es posible que sea mejor que cada jugador almacene su propia sigma y hacer cambios en algunas partes del código. 2. Los jugadores solo deben mantener la memoria en cada partida (de ronda 1 a ronda 3). Es decir, en cada simulación y muestra, cada jugador debe ser reiniciado para comenzar la nueva partida sin señales en la memoria.

Comment: 3. El juego pretende ser una simulación de agentes enseñándose señales ("S1","S2","S3","S4"). Hay cuatro agentes, que se muestran señales en parejas, y dependiendo de una serie de parámetros, mantienen la suya original o copian la del jugador con el que están emparejados. Por ilustrar, las señales digamos que representan la palabra que un individuo usa para representar un concepto abstracto. 4. Hasta ahora, lo que intentaba era crear dentro de `def jugar` las listas aux, para luego compararlas con s_inicial y en consecuencia actualizar la lista s.

Comment: 5. Si se observa, ver `print(senales)`, en la ronda 1 cada jugador genera su señal propia. Es a partir de este momento que la producción de las señales que los jugadores producen se verá afectada por la ecuación `def with_b`. 6. El objetivo ahora, es que la sigma de cada jugador se vaya actualizando de ronda en ronda según la relación entre `aux ` y `s`.

Comment: @abufalia gracias de nuevo por el tiempo invertido y enhorabuena por el código. Es increíble que puedas haberte puesto tan al día tan rápidamente. Ahora lo que estoy intentando impelmentar es básicamente lo que comentaba en la pregunta. Para cada jugador y ronda, si su aux coincide con el valor el valor s_inicial indicado, su sigma se multiplicará por un factor de corrección.

Comment: así, por ejemplo. Si en una ronda determinada el jugador 1 genera aux1=[1,0,0,0], dado que esta lista coincide con s_inicial_1=[1,0,0,0], su sigma se multiplicará por cf_pos. De esta manera el nuevo valor actualizado s1 operará para jugador 1 en la función def with_b. Si por el contrario, jugador 1 genera aux1=[0,0,1,0], dado que esta lista no coincide con s_inicial_1=[1,0,0,0], el valor de s1 (para ese jugador) se multiplicará por cf_neg. Los valores de s1 o s2 de cada jugador se irán actualizando acumulativamente ronda a ronda.

Comment: Lo que he estado intentando hasta ahora es generar una lista idéntica a aux pero dentro de la partida, para así hacer la comparación entre cada aux y s_inical en cada ronda del juego. Dime por favor si esta explicación es suficientemente clara o si precisas de más detalles.

Comment: @pyring He añadido una actualización a la respuesta. Por favor verifica si se comporta como querías, porque no estoy del todo seguro (ya que sigo sin entender el objeto del "juego")

Comment: @abufalia muchas gracias. Mañana estaré realizando simulaciones sobre una implementación extendida de este código para verificar si se comporta dentro de los parámetros esperados. Te comentaré algo pronto.

Comment: @abufalia he realizado simulaciones con 8 jugadores y 7 rondas. Al comparar simulaciones para `cf_neg=1.0` y `cf_neg=0.5` los resultados son diferentes y según el comportamiento que cabría esperar. Se observan mayores diferencias cuando el parámetro `b=0.8` aproximadamente. Esto me hace pensar que los cambios de sigma se están implementando correctamente y que están afectando las probabilidades que arroja la función `def with_b`. Es decir, que todo indica que funciona. Tengo todavía que verificar todo con más simulaciones, pero gracias por la gran ayuda.